# How to connect items with keys for flat structure? Angular 2 + Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable

I have a general question how to use flat database structure in relation to other properties.

[image: my structure]

so as you can see, here is my firebase strucure. every campaign has many codes

campaigns -> userID -> campaignID -> properties

codes -> userID -> campaignID -> codeID -> properties

Whats the best / normal way to "connect" them? Of course I get two different observables but I cant really figure out whats the way to show the codes that belong to the campaign after I iterated through the campaigns with ngFor?

Regards

Comment: Since campaings and codes have the same identifiers, you just have to get the the code and put it in campaings, make a reference to it. Then you loop over campaings which now have the codes inside.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be faster if you just combine the codes inside a campaign.

```
-> campaigns
   -> [userId]
     -> [campaignId]
          -> active: false
          -> name: "sadasd"
          -> timestamp: 1507923847578
          -> codes :
              -> [codeId]
                 -> name: "test1"
              -> [codeId]
                 -> name: "test2"
     -> [campaignId]
          -> active: true
          -> name: "Test1"
          -> timestamp: 1507923845531
          -> codes :
              -> [codeId]
                 -> name: "test3"
              -> [codeId]
                 -> name: "test4"
```

And then use `*ngFor='let campaign of campaigns | async'`

inside that, use `*ngFor='let code of campaign.codes'`

Comment: But I’m also having downloads [codeId] with new properties. So every download of every code is tracked with additional information so if we have 30 codes per campaign with thousands of downloads it’s going be a lot of data just to get the codes list. Even though my question is more how i would connect same keys of different properties no matter about the structure in front. I’m pretty new to angular and firebase

Comment: besides that i forgot to say, that the codes have to have public read access